# New install using a wireless keyboard and mouse

Tags: installation, wireless, keyboard, mouse

This is a very basic question but I do not know the answer. I am building a new PC from scratch and wondered if the **Ubuntu Installer** will recognize a wireless keyboard and mouse during the installation.

Thank you very much!

Mariano

Comment: Would it not be possible to borrow a wired keyboard and mouse for installation, if not you can usually pick them up for around a fiver.

Comment: Of course they would work. You might be surprised that they would work perfectly well with your BIOS, let alone ubuntu installer.

Comment: Are you referring to Bluetooth wireless devices (which the operating system might need to know about), or proprietary ones that only work with their own dongle (which often just look like standard wired USB devices)?

Answer (score 2):

Wireless keyboards/mice speak the same protocols as wired ones so it should not be a problem.

I have a (USB) Logitech wireless keyboard and mouse and both I can use while installing.

Comment: I had several wireless keyboards/mice from many different brands (includign even a Microsoft mouse). They all worked well :) Only with bluetooth devices problems may occur.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone for your answer. I will try with a Logitech wireless (not bluetooth).